# Win32: How to crash?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp, error-reporting, windows-error-reporting

i'm trying to figure out where Windows Error Reports are saved; i hit **Send** on some earlier today, but i forgot that i want to "view the details" so i can examine the memory minidumps.

But i cannot find where they are stored (and google doesn't know).

So i want to write a dummy application that will crash, show the WER dialog, let me click "view the details" so i can get to the folder where the dumps are saved.

How can i crash on Windows?

**Edit:** The reason i ask is because i've tried overflowing the stack, and floating point dividing by zero. Stack Overflow makes the app vanish, but no WER dialog popped up. Floating point division by zero results in +INF, but no exception, and no crash.

Comment: I got one of these with windows, for FREE

Comment: @M28: You should contact the developer of the application that's crashing. In my case it's our in-process COM object loaded into IIS6's worker space though ASP scripting host.

Comment: It's called windows, where do I find its developer? :B

Comment: @M28. i'd be **very** interested to see where you are experiencing a crash in Windows itself. Even crashes in Windows Explorer or Internet Explorer are caused by 3rd party extensions. Windows is the most tested piece of software there is. Odds are very low that you've found a bug in Windows itself.

Comment: No offense, but you have no sense of humor.

Comment: maybe you can get some tips how to crash Windows from the BF3 developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be a good start:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char *pointer = NULL;
   printf("crash please %s", *pointer);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might want to set the pointer to something other than NULL as it's likely printf checks for that. 0xDEADBEEF perhaps?

Comment: i used your idea, i cast null to an object, then began calling methods. *boom*

Comment: @Billy ONeal: It's really not `printf` that's crashing, it's the attempt to dereference a null pointer. `printf` was just to be cute, `char *pointer = NULL; char crash = *pointer;` would have worked just as well.

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that little * character :)

Answer (score 6):

You guys are all so verbose!  :-)

Here's a compact way to do it:

```
*((int*)0)=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming the memory dumps are still around. Once they are sent, AFAIK the dumps are deleted from the machine.

The dumps themselves should be located in %TEMP% somewhere.

As far as crashing, that's not difficult, just do something that causes a segfault.

Comment: It's difficult enough that my first two attempts couldn't do it. KevinK's idea, referencing address 0x00000000 worked.

Comment: And you seem to be right, the memory dumps, on XP, vanish once sent. Vista keeps them, as part of the **Problem Reports and Solutions Center**.

Answer (score 1):

```
void crash(void)
{
    char* a = 0;
    *a = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will trigger the Error Reporting dialog, but you could try division by zero.

Comment: That just throws an exception. It doesn't crash on Win32. (Note that I don't mean C++ exceptions, I mean Win32 SEH)

Answer (score 0):

The officially-supported ways to trigger a crash on purpose can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545484(v=VS.85).aspx

Basically:

> With USB keyboards, you must enable
>   the keyboard-initiated crash in the
>   registry. In the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid\Parameters,
>   create a value named
>   CrashOnCtrlScroll, and set it equal to
>   a REG_DWORD value of 0x01.

Then:

> You must restart the system for these
>   settings to take effect.
>
> After this is completed, the keyboard
>   crash can be initiated by using the
>   following hotkey sequence: Hold down
>   the rightmost CTRL key, and press the
>   SCROLL LOCK key twice.

No programming necessary ;)  No wheel reinvention here :)

Comment: How does this method know which process is mine that i'm debugging? (Rhetorical question; your answer is to trigger a kernel mode exception and blue-screen; i want to trigger default crash handling for a user-mode process - my process)

Comment: My bad.  I had thought you were trying to trigger a general crash to look at the dump files, not a specific process crash.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting to know how to crash Windows.  But why not have a look at

```
%allusersprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Dr Watson\
```

first? Look out for application specific crashdata folders as well, I found e.g.

```
...\FirefoxPortable\Data\profile\minidumps\
```

and

```
...\OpenOfficePortable\Data\settings\user\crashdata\.
```

Comment: Why? Why not look there? Because i don't know about that path - and that folder doesn't exist on my machine.